# Solve $\begin{cases}x^2+xy-y^2+2x+y=10\\3x^2-2xy+2y^2-5x-2y=22\end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve $$\begin{cases}x^2+xy-y^2+2x+y=10\\3x^2-2xy+2y^2-5x-2y=22\end{cases}.$$

I am not sure how to approach the problem. I tried mulptiplying the first equation by $2,$ then I added the equation to the first one but it seemed useless at the end. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Have you tried extracting perfect squares?

Comment: Thank you for the response. No, I haven't. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @KaloyanK.: What if you add 2 times the first equation to the second?

Comment: It's not useless. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741158/small-confusion-when-solving-the-system-of-nonlinear-equations-begincases-3y?rq=1) how to finish by factorizing. It gives $(x,y)=(3,-1),(3,5)$ as real solutions.

Comment: @Moo This solves the problem, I think!

Comment: @VIVID: Agreed - the rest is simple after the observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were right to multiply the first equation by two. Now adding them together, we get: $$5x^2-x-42=0$$
which you can solve by the quadratic equation: $$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt {1+4\cdot5\cdot42}}{10}=\frac{1\pm 29}{10}=3, -2.8$$
Then just force through the first equation to find each $y$